lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': but the file exists on location
I had an running app, which i than added some new things and than i got the error "Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding" when building Flutter app"
so i did as i was told and created a new project and dropped every old file in the new project while checking that i dont drag the code in the new project what kills the v1/v2 thing. some bugfixing later im now in a stage where my VS code doesnt scream at me with 1k errors but now i cant run or build it...
i now get:

PS C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly> flutter build apk --debug
lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
translate: cant find data
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 2s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
3,6s Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

but it is there: Project Structure
I already tried to add 20 different Launch options for Flutter and/or Dart with direct path to main.dart but nothing worked. Im exhausted.
Running code from: PS
C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly>  file is
in:
C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly\lib\main.dart
open for every new idea i guess?
Edit_1:
after some changes i now get:
PS C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly> flutter build apk

lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

package:Verpfly/main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception

this is my main.dart:
// lib/main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'licenses/custom_license.dart'; // Importiere die benutzerdefinierten Lizenzen
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'models/entry.dart';
import 'models/settings.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'pages/entries_page.dart';
import 'pages/edit_entry_page.dart';
import 'pages/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_exit_app/flutter_exit_app.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'utils/constants.dart'; // Hinzugefügt
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart'; // Für App-Versionierung
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize(); // AdMob SDK initialisieren

  // Hive initialisieren
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  // Adapter registrieren
  Hive.registerAdapter(EntryAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(SettingsAdapter());

  await Hive.openBox<Entry>('entries');
  await Hive.openBox<Settings>('settings');

  // Versionsprüfung und Migration
  await checkAndMigrateDatabase();

  registerCustomLicense(); // Registriere die benutzerdefinierten Lizenzen

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> checkAndMigrateDatabase() async {
  final settingsBox = Hive.box<Settings>('settings');
  Settings? settings = settingsBox.get('settings');

  int storedDbVersion = settings?.dbVersion ?? 0;
  int currentDbVersion = Constants.currentDbVersion;

  if (storedDbVersion < currentDbVersion) {
    // Migration erforderlich
    await migrateDatabase(fromVersion: storedDbVersion, toVersion: currentDbVersion);

    // Aktualisiere die gespeicherte Datenbankversion
    if (settings != null) {
      settings.dbVersion = currentDbVersion;
      await settings.save();
    } else {
      // Falls keine Einstellungen vorhanden sind, erstelle neue
      settings = Settings(
        ownerName: settings?.ownerName ?? '',
        companyName: settings?.companyName ?? '',
        dbVersion: currentDbVersion,
      );
      await settingsBox.put('settings', settings);
    }
  }
}

Future<void> migrateDatabase({required int fromVersion, required int toVersion}) async {
  for (int version = fromVersion + 1; version <= toVersion; version++) {
    switch (version) {
      case 1:
        await migrateToVersion1();
        break;
      // Weitere Migrationen hier hinzufügen
      default:
        throw Exception('Unbekannte Datenbankversion: $version');
    }
  }
}

Future<void> migrateToVersion1() async {
  var entriesBox = Hive.box<Entry>('entries');
  for (int i = 0; i < entriesBox.length; i++) {
    Entry? entry = entriesBox.getAt(i);
    if (entry != null) {
      entry.breakfastsProvided = entry.breakfastsProvided ?? 0;
      entry.lunchesProvided = entry.lunchesProvided ?? 0;
      entry.dinnersProvided = entry.dinnersProvided ?? 0;
      await entry.save();
    }
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key}); // const-Konstruktor hinzugefügt

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'verpfly',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // Lokalisierung hinzugefügt
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('de'), // Deutsch
      ],
      home: HomePage(),
      routes: {
        '/entries': (context) => EntriesPage(),
        '/settings': (context) => SettingsPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class DatabaseErrorApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DatabaseErrorApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DatabaseErrorPage(),
    );
  }
}

class DatabaseErrorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DatabaseErrorPage({super.key});

  void _handleUserChoice(BuildContext context, bool deleteDb) async {
    if (deleteDb) {
      // Löschen der bestehenden Datenbank
      await Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk('entries');
      await Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk('settings');
      // Starten der App neu
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
      );
    } else {
      // App schließen
      FlutterExitApp.exitApp();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Datenbankfehler'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Die bestehende Datenbank ist beschädigt oder entspricht nicht den aktuellen Anforderungen.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _handleUserChoice(context, true),
                child: Text('Datenbank löschen und neu erstellen'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _handleUserChoice(context, false),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),
                child: Text('App schließen'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you provide your main.dart? maybe you modify something in your main() function.

provided in editeted post

can you try to run it with out try-catch in your main?

Commanded it out - no change

oke then, try to run your project in terminal with this command flutter run -t lib/main.dart

than i get this error
PS C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly> flutter run -t lib/main.dart
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone16k x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             12,0s
Error: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly\build, but the
tool couldn't find it.

I guess the problem is in vscode configuration. Since you use vscode to run flutter, you need to configure the vscode for flutter project. Usually this configuration is generated automatically by vscode, i don't know why yours not. So to add configuration manually, follow this step:

Open Command Palette in your vscode by Shift + Command + P (Mac) / Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows/Linux) / Application Menu > View > Command Palette
Type "Add Configuration" then enter.
Add the minimal configuration like this:

{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "verpfly",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart"
        }
    ]
}


If you want to see more attribute check at Launch Configuration


Then save, and try to flutter run or flutter run -t lib/main.dart


Your configuration settings should be available in .vscode folder


yeah i did delete that in the rage of not getting it to work yesterday but since than i had it in a couple times and deleted it again. WIth the launch.json activ i get:
PS C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              4,8s
Error: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\Users\Bassi\Documents\VMP\flutter_application_1\verpfly\build, but the tool couldn't find
it.

and if i do flutter build apk i get:
lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
package:Verpfly/main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
